# predict the outcome numbers using a list

Tags: python

I have 3 lists with 3 sets of integers. I want to predict the outcome numbers using a list or by whatever other means is out there.

```
List1 = [0 0 2 0 1 2]
List2 = [3 0 1 0 1 0]
List3 = [0 0 2 1 1 1]
```

Im working in the first column, I was thinking of using a double if statement something like:

```
if 3 is in spot 0 of any list 
and 0 is in spot 0 of any list

print 2
```

The other thing is I want to do this for all the other columns as well.

I know this is not complete but its on my mind like this and ive been

searching around and found nothing to solve this problem.

I would greatly appeciate any response to this question.

Comment: please explain the "outcome".

Comment: Does not make much sense what you are asking without clear explanation. We must not guess what "outcome" means

Comment: the if statement starts the search and the print 2 was the outcome. trying to predict an outcome.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You cant define a list delimited with space; you have to use a comma',' instead.

```
l1=[0,0,2,0,1,2]
l2=[3,0,1,0,1,0,]
l3=[0,0,2,1,1,1]

spot0_list = zip(l1,l2,l3)[0]
if 3 in spot0_list and  0  in spot0_list:
    print 2
```

And, if there are too many lists, you can use `set`:

```
spot0_list = set(zip(l1,l2,l3)[0])
```

Comment: Thats cool. So would repeating the code be the fastest solution?

Comment: @All who have downvoted: Well, If I am getting downvotes for this answer, whosoever is downvoting, please furnish a better answer so that I too can learn

Comment: @Howie: What do you want to repeat in the code ??

Comment: Probably, somebody considers my answer is not correct.

Comment: no your answer will take this a long ways.  Its correct.

Comment: @Howie: What is outcome?

Comment: For the other columns, that should be left as an exercise to you. 
Hint: remove the `[0]` in the line: `spot0_list = zip(l1,l2,l3)`.
This will return you a list which you can iterate over for other columns too.
If you accept the answer, I can move on to some other question

Comment: @GodMan: -1 for not showing any sign of understanding on the question op asks.

Comment: @junjanes: Dude, Not everynody in this community is writing production level code. Somebody might require some help for understanding small things.
According to me, Howie just wants some decision making based on the data in some column of the list. And, even if he is new to python, that does not mean we should downvote his basic questions

Comment: ok, I planned to. Just thought there was some really hard code to this.

Comment: yes Im still in diapers with python.  I dont mean to offend anyone here I think this is a cool site with cool, talented, and intelligent people.